# Error when loading data into Postgres table from SAS(Invalid input syntax for integer)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas

Error when loading data into Postgres table from SAS(Invalid input syntax for integer)

I am using SAS Data Integration Studio with SCD Type 1 loader to load data into PostGres Table.

First of all, the issue that I am facing is the error message:
ERROR: CLI execute error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1372.8"; Error while executing the query

I've searched the entire table(170 rows) and there is no data with the value of 1372.8 or even close to it.

The postgres table has a few non-nullable columns and i have made sure all 170 records contain values. There is no record with missing value.

However, I am getting this strange error. I have also browse through stackoverflow but it seems like this has nothing to do with SAS but postgres. However, the value that i load into postgres is of same data type, always numeric and i have no clue why is this error prompting.

Log file:

```
NOTE: Appending WORK.WVVOL13 to NETCAP.MasterAssetRenewable.
NOTE: FORCE is specified, so dropping/truncating will occur.
NOTE: There were 18 observations read from the data set WORK.WVVOL13.
NOTE: 17 observations added.
NOTE: The data set NETCAP.MasterAssetRenewable has . observations and 18 variables.
ERROR: CLI execute error: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1372.8";
```

Code from SCD Type 1 Loader:

```
/*==========================================================================* 
 * Step:            SCD Type 1                            A5KQQF32.C20002Y5 * 
 * Transform:       SCD Type 1                                              * 
 * Description:                                                             * 
 *                                                                          * 
 * Source Table:    User Written -                        A5KQQF32.C90001ZV * 
 *                   work.ncp_asset_re_toloadnew                            * 
 * Target Tables:   MasterAssetRenewable -                A5KQQF32.BE0000X2 * 
 *                   netcap.MasterAssetRenewable                            * 
 *                  Cross reference -                     A5KQQF32.C90001ZW * 
 *                   work.MasterAssetRenewable_xref                         * 
 *                  Changed records - work.WVVOJQO        A5KQQF32.C90001ZX * 
 *                  New records - work.WVVOL13            A5KQQF32.C90001ZY * 
 *==========================================================================*/ 

options VALIDVARNAME = ANY VALIDMEMNAME = EXTEND; 

%let transformID = %quote(A5KQQF32.C20002Y5);
%let trans_rc = 0;
%let etls_stepStartTime = %sysfunc(datetime(), datetime20.); 

%let SYSLAST = %nrquote(work."ncp_asset_re_toloadnew"n); 

%macro etls_scd_type_1;

/*---- Delete any pre-existing work tables  ----*/ 
proc datasets lib = work nolist nowarn memtype = (data view);
   delete etls_xref;
quit;

proc datasets lib = work nolist nowarn memtype = (data view);
   delete "WVVOJQO"n;
quit;

proc datasets lib = work nolist nowarn memtype = (data view);
   delete "WVVOL13"n;
quit;

/* Determine if the table exists  */ 
%let etls_tableExist = %eval(%sysfunc(exist(netcap."MasterAssetRenewable"n, DATA)) or 
      %sysfunc(exist(netcap."MasterAssetRenewable"n, VIEW))); 

/*---- Create a new table  ----*/ 
%if (&etls_tableExist eq 0) %then 
%do;  /* if table does not exist  */ 

   %put %str(NOTE: Creating table ...);

   data netcap."MasterAssetRenewable"n
           (dbnull = (
                      "Id"n = NO
                      "DetailType"n = NO
                      "DependableFactor"n = NO
                      "StatusType"n = NO
                      "DeclaredGenerationMd"n = NO
                      "ActualGenerationMd"n = NO
                      "BusinessAreaId"n = YES
                      "PmuId"n = YES
                      "PpuId"n = YES
                      "CreatedFromId"n = YES
                      "CustomerName"n = YES
                      "CustomerNumber"n = YES
                      "SsuId"n = YES
                      "FeederNo"n = YES
                      "Lat"n = YES
                      "Lng"n = YES
                      "ReCapacity"n = NO
                      "TargetCommDate"n = NO));
      attrib "Id"n length = 8
         format = 20.
         informat = 20.
         label = 'Id'; 
      attrib "DetailType"n length = 8
         format = 11.
         informat = 11.
         label = 'DetailType'; 
      attrib "DependableFactor"n length = 8
         label = 'DependableFactor'; 
      attrib "StatusType"n length = 8
         format = 11.
         informat = 11.
         label = 'StatusType'; 
      attrib "DeclaredGenerationMd"n length = 8
         label = 'DeclaredGenerationMd'; 
      attrib "ActualGenerationMd"n length = 8
         label = 'ActualGenerationMd'; 
      attrib "BusinessAreaId"n length = 8
         format = 20.
         informat = 20.
         label = 'BusinessAreaId'; 
      attrib "PmuId"n length = 8
         format = 20.
         informat = 20.
         label = 'PmuId'; 
      attrib "PpuId"n length = 8
         format = 20.
         informat = 20.
         label = 'PpuId'; 
      attrib "CreatedFromId"n length = 8
         format = 20.
         informat = 20.
         label = 'CreatedFromId'; 
      attrib "CustomerName"n length = $1024
         format = $1024.
         informat = $1024.
         label = 'CustomerName'; 
      attrib "CustomerNumber"n length = $1024
         format = $1024.
         informat = $1024.
         label = 'CustomerNumber'; 
      attrib "SsuId"n length = 8
         format = 20.
         informat = 20.
         label = 'SsuId'; 
      attrib "FeederNo"n length = $1024
         format = $1024.
         informat = $1024.
         label = 'FeederNo'; 
      attrib "Lat"n length = 8
         label = 'Lat'; 
      attrib "Lng"n length = 8
         label = 'Lng'; 
      attrib "ReCapacity"n length = 8
         format = 11.
         informat = 11.
         label = 'ReCapacity'; 
      attrib "TargetCommDate"n length = 8
         format = DATETIME25.6
         informat = DATETIME25.6
         label = 'TargetCommDate'; 
      call missing(of _all_);
      stop;
   run;

   %rcSet(&syserr); 

   /*---- Create the indexes for a table  ----*/ 
   %put %str(NOTE: Creating indexes ...);
   %macro etls_createIndexes;
      proc sql; 
         connect to POSTGRES
         ( 
             DATABASE=netcap SERVER="unadevsaswas01.hq.tnb.com.my" AUTHDOMAIN="NetcapAuth" 
         ); 
         reset noprint; 
         execute 
         ( 
            create index "IX_MasterAssetRenewable_PpuId"
               on "MasterAssetRenewable"
                    ("PpuId") 
         ) by POSTGRES; 

         %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

         execute 
         ( 
            create index "IX_MasterAssetRenewable_PmuId"
               on "MasterAssetRenewable"
                    ("PmuId") 
         ) by POSTGRES; 

         %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

         execute 
         ( 
            create index "IX_MasterAssetRenewable_CreatedFromId"
               on "MasterAssetRenewable"
                    ("CreatedFromId") 
         ) by POSTGRES; 

         %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

         execute 
         ( 
            create index "IX_MasterAssetRenewable_BusinessAreaId"
               on "MasterAssetRenewable"
                    ("BusinessAreaId") 
         ) by POSTGRES; 

         %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

         execute 
         ( 
            create index "IX_MasterAssetRenewable_SsuId"
               on "MasterAssetRenewable"
                    ("SsuId") 
         ) by POSTGRES; 

         %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

         disconnect from POSTGRES; 
      quit; 

      %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

   %mend etls_createIndexes;
   %etls_createIndexes;

   /*---- Create the integrity constraints for a table  ----*/ 
   %put %str(NOTE: Creating integrity constraints ...);
   proc sql;
      connect to POSTGRES
      ( 
          DATABASE=netcap SERVER="unadevsaswas01.hq.tnb.com.my" AUTHDOMAIN="NetcapAuth" 
      ); 
      reset noprint; 

      execute 
      ( 
         alter table "MasterAssetRenewable"      
            add primary key ("Id")
      ) by POSTGRES; 

      %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

      execute 
      ( 
         alter table "MasterAssetRenewable"      
            add foreign key ("PmuId") references "MasterAssetPmu"
      ) by POSTGRES; 

      %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

      execute 
      ( 
         alter table "MasterAssetRenewable"      
            add foreign key ("PpuId") references "MasterAssetPpu"
      ) by POSTGRES; 

      %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

      disconnect from POSTGRES; 
   quit;

   %rcSet(&sqlrc); 

%end;  /* if table does not exist  */ 

/* Determine if the table exists  */ 
%let etls_tableExist = %eval(%sysfunc(exist(work."MasterAssetRenewable_xref"n, DATA)) or 
      %sysfunc(exist(work."MasterAssetRenewable_xref"n, VIEW))); 

/*---- Create a new table  ----*/ 
%if (&etls_tableExist eq 0) %then 
%do;  /* if table does not exist  */ 

   %put %str(NOTE: Creating table ...);

   data work."MasterAssetRenewable_xref"n;
      attrib "Id"n length = 8
         format = 20.
         informat = 20.
         label = 'Id'; 
      attrib "compare_digest"n length = $32
         format = $32.
         informat = $32.; 
      call missing(of _all_);
      stop;
   run;

   %rcSet(&syserr); 

   /*---- Create the integrity constraints for a table  ----*/ 
   %put %str(NOTE: Creating integrity constraints ...);
   proc datasets library=work nolist;
      modify "MasterAssetRenewable_xref"n;
         ic create not null ("Id"n);
   quit;

   %rcSet(&syserr); 

%end;  /* if table does not exist  */ 

proc datasets lib = work nolist nowarn memtype = (data view);
   delete W159RVJL;
quit;

proc sql;
   create view work.W159RVJL as
      select
         "Id"n   
            format = 20.
            informat = 20.,
         "DetailType"n,
         "DependableFactor"n,
         "StatusType"n,
         "DeclaredGenerationMd"n,
         "ActualGenerationMd"n,
         "BusinessAreaId"n,
         "PmuId"n   
            format = 20.
            informat = 20.,
         "PpuId"n   
            format = 20.
            informat = 20.,
         "CreatedFromId"n,
         "CustomerName"n length = 1024   
            format = $1024.
            informat = $1024.,
         "CustomerNumber"n length = 1024   
            format = $1024.
            informat = $1024.,
         "SsuId"n,
         "FeederNo"n length = 1024   
            format = $1024.
            informat = $1024.,
         "Lat"n,
         "Lng"n,
         "ReCapacity"n   
            format = 11.
            informat = 11.,
         "TargetCommDate"n   
            format = DATETIME25.6
            informat = DATETIME25.6
   from work."ncp_asset_re_toloadnew"n
   ;
quit;

%let SYSLAST = work.W159RVJL;

/* create work xref table  */ 
data work.etls_xref(keep = Id compare_digest);

   length compare_digest $ 32;

   set netcap."MasterAssetRenewable"n( keep = Id ReCapacity FeederNo DeclaredGenerationMd);

   /* create digest - version 2.1  */ 
   compare_digest = put(md5(catq(' ', ReCapacity, FeederNo, DeclaredGenerationMd)), $hex32.);

run;
%rcSet(&syscc); 

/*---- SCD Type 1 processing: hash lookup method  ----*/ 
data 
   /* Changed Records Table  */ 
   work."WVVOJQO"n( keep = Id ReCapacity FeederNo DeclaredGenerationMd compare_digest)

   /* New Records Table  */ 
   work."WVVOL13"n;

   drop source_digest;

   length source_digest $ 32;

   if 0 then
      set work.etls_xref;

   if _N_ eq 1 then
   do;
      declare hash hct(dataset: 'work.etls_xref', hashexp: 10);
                   hct.defineKey("Id");
                   hct.defineData("Id", "compare_digest");
                   hct.defineDone();
   end;

   set work.W159RVJL;

   /* create digest - version 2.1  */ 
   source_digest = put(md5(catq(' ', ReCapacity, FeederNo, DeclaredGenerationMd)), $hex32.);

   /* match  */ 
   if hct.find() eq 0 then
   do;
      /* scd type 1 records  */ 
      if source_digest ne compare_digest then
      do;
         compare_digest = source_digest;
         output work."WVVOJQO"n;
      end;
   end;
   /* new records  */ 
   else if hct.find() ne 0 then
   do;
      compare_digest = source_digest;
      output work."WVVOL13"n;
   end;

run;
%rcSet(&syscc); 

/* changed records table - record check  */ 
%let etls_recCheckExist = 0; 
%let etls_change_rows = 0; 
%macro etls_recordCheck; 
   %let etls_recCheckExist = %eval(%sysfunc(exist(work."WVVOJQO"n, DATA)) or 
         %sysfunc(exist(work."WVVOJQO"n, VIEW))); 

   %if (&etls_recCheckExist) %then
   %do;
      %local etls_syntaxcheck; 
      %let etls_syntaxcheck = %sysfunc(getoption(syntaxcheck)); 
      /* Turn off syntaxcheck option to perform following steps  */ 
      options nosyntaxcheck;

      data _null_; 
         set work."WVVOJQO"n( obs=1 ); 
         call symput("etls_change_rows",'1'); 
      run; 
      /* Reset syntaxcheck option to previous setting  */ 
      options &etls_syntaxcheck; 
   %end;
%mend etls_recordCheck;
%etls_recordCheck;

%rcSet(&syscc); 

/* new records table - record check  */ 
%let etls_recCheckExist = 0; 
%let etls_new_rows = 0; 
%macro etls_recordCheck; 
   %let etls_recCheckExist = %eval(%sysfunc(exist(work."WVVOL13"n, DATA)) or 
         %sysfunc(exist(work."WVVOL13"n, VIEW))); 

   %if (&etls_recCheckExist) %then
   %do;
      %local etls_syntaxcheck; 
      %let etls_syntaxcheck = %sysfunc(getoption(syntaxcheck)); 
      /* Turn off syntaxcheck option to perform following steps  */ 
      options nosyntaxcheck;

      data _null_; 
         set work."WVVOL13"n( obs=1 ); 
         call symput("etls_new_rows",'1'); 
      run; 
      /* Reset syntaxcheck option to previous setting  */ 
      options &etls_syntaxcheck; 
   %end;
%mend etls_recordCheck;
%etls_recordCheck;

%rcSet(&syscc); 

/*---- target table: update/append rows  ----*/ 

/* target table: update change rows  */ 
%if &etls_change_rows ge 1 %then
%do;
   proc sql;
      update netcap."MasterAssetRenewable"n as m
         set "ReCapacity"n = (select "ReCapacity"n from work."WVVOJQO"n as t
                  where m."Id"n = t."Id"n),
             "FeederNo"n = (select "FeederNo"n from work."WVVOJQO"n as t
                  where m."Id"n = t."Id"n),
             "DeclaredGenerationMd"n = (select "DeclaredGenerationMd"n from work."WVVOJQO"n as t
                  where m."Id"n = t."Id"n)
         where exists (select * from work."WVVOJQO"n as t
            where m."Id"n = t."Id"n);
   quit;
   %rcSet(&syscc);
%end;

/* target table - append new rows  */ 
%if &etls_new_rows ge 1 %then
%do;
   proc append base = netcap."MasterAssetRenewable"n
               data = work."WVVOL13"n force nowarn;
   run;
   %rcSet(&syscc);
%end;

/*---- cross reference table: update/append rows  ----*/ 

/* cross reference table: update change rows  */ 
%if &etls_change_rows ge 1 %then
%do;
   proc sql;
      update work."MasterAssetRenewable_xref"n as m
         set compare_digest = (select compare_digest from work."WVVOJQO"n as t
                  where m."Id"n = t."Id"n)
         where exists (select * from work."WVVOJQO"n as t
            where m."Id"n = t."Id"n);
   quit;
   %rcSet(&syscc);
%end;

/* cross reference table - append new rows  */ 
%if &etls_new_rows ge 1 %then
%do;
   proc append base = work."MasterAssetRenewable_xref"n
               data = work."WVVOL13"n( keep = Id compare_digest)
   force nowarn;
   run;
   %rcSet(&syscc);
%end;

/* Delete work.etls_xref table  */ 
proc datasets lib = work nolist nowarn memtype = (data view);
   delete etls_xref;
quit;

%mend etls_scd_type_1;

/* execute etls_scd_type_1  */ 
%etls_scd_type_1



/** Step end SCD Type 1 **/
```

Comment: Are you really trying to make 20 digit numbers in SAS?  You cannot represent 20 decimal digits exactly as 64bit floating point numbers.  Why not make those identifiers as character strings instead?

Comment: Hi @Tom I've set all numeric to FORMAT 8. and removed all INFORMAT.

Comment: However, I am still getting the same exact error

Comment: It is possible some engine generated SQL is getting truncated or clipped.  What are the options of the NETCAP libname ? Does the same error occur with only 1 row ? How about 2 ?  Can you find the number of rows that cause a transition for ok to error ?  Did you use SASTRACE options to observer the details of POSTGRES engine activity ?